# Uninstall add-on setup when uninstall the Main setup using Wix

Tags: wix

I am using wix in my installer,
I need to uninstall add-on Setup while uninstall the Main setup,
I am using the below code in Main setup wix,

```
  <CustomAction Id="UNINSTALL_ADDON" Return="asyncNoWait" Execute="immediate" ExeCommand="msiexec.exe /x [add-onProductID] /qn” Property="add-onProductID" />
```

Below code in InstallExecute Table
`<Custom Action="UNINSTALL_ADDON" Sequence="1282">(REMOVE="ALL")</Custom>`

I am using the below property

```
<Property Id=" add-onProductID" Value="NULL" />
```

I have read the add-on Property Id from registry and pass it set to add-onProductID using CustomAction while uninstall the main setup.
This won’t help. Could you please help me to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install or uninstall another MSI during InstallExecuteSequence because Windows Installer doesn't support simultaneous install processes.

A solution is to make sure that your custom action is scheduled after InstallFinalize action (it's sequence is greater than InstallFinalize).

Comment: I have set the sequence after installFinalize but no luck. It return values 1631 with out any meg in uninstall log file, Do you have any Idea?